# Sonar 5.3 force issues report generation on publish analysis mode

Tags: report, sonarqube, teamcity

I've been working with Sonar 4.5, although I would like to migrate to version 5.3. During the tests I've noticed that Issues Report is not getting generated when analysis type is publish (it needs to be preview), although it's a need for us to store the analysis to the DB on each Sonar run.

My question is, is there a way to force it to generate the issues report even running on publish mode (I suspect this limitation is related to the fact that publish mode takes longer to finish).

PS: I need the Issues Report in order to extract metrics from it and publish it on TeamCity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible anymore. If you want to retrieve some information from SonarQube, you should use the standard public WS to achieve this.

1. Once the analysis has been sent to the server, you can check `<work_dir>/report-task.txt` to know which URL to call in order to know when the report is processed (URL is given by the `ceTaskUrl` property in this file)
2. Once the call to this WS returns the `SUCCESS` status, you can query the `/api/resources` WS (using the key of the project given by the `projectKey` property) to get any information you want on your project that has just been analysed.

Comment: so how do I export a report from Sonar 5.3 ? Can all this be achieved just using the WS or should I call other commands ?